# Quick Steps for Lotus Notes like in Outlook

Tags: lotus-notes

Is there an equivalent for the Quick Steps of Outlook for Lotus Notes Client?

Explanation: by Quick Steps in Outlook the user can pre-define a batch of steps, that are executed by pressing on the Button on the toolbar.

Or this functionality must be implemented as some kind of extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to automate Tasks in Notes you can use [Agents](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_CREATING_AN_AGENT.html). Besides some predefined "[Simple actions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_TABLE_OF_SIMPLE_ACTIONS_FOR_AUTOMATION_FEATURES.html?view=kc)" you can use Formula, Lotusscript and Java to do more complex actions.